# redash change nginx port

Tags: docker-compose, redash

I installed redash with dock-compose on an ubuntu machine, in the " docker-compose.production.yml", nginx port is "80:80", now I want to change a port for redash, how should I do? Just change it to "5433:80" does not work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn5u3.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have set it correctly, change the line `80:80` to `5433:80` will forward the nginx port to `5433` on the host machine. Have you re-created the image with this command?

`docker-compose up -d --force-recreate`